# Sails.js background processing loop, not related to connections

Tags: sails.js

If you have a process loop you want to run continuously after delays with setTimeout (regardless of connections) where would that code go and be executed from?

It looks like the code would go in the services directory, but where do I start the loop?  I tried in the app.js, but that doesn't work once sails is lifted it doesn't look like

**Simple Example**

```
// MyFoo.js
module.exports = {

    shouldFoo: true,

    doFoo: function(){
        if(this.shouldFoo){
            console.log('fooing ...');
            setTimeout(foo, 1000);
        } else {
            this.shutdownFoo();
        }
    },

    shutdownFoo: function(){
        // finish up process
    }
}
```

Then where do I put:

```
var fooer = require('./api/services/MyFoo.js');
fooer.doFoo();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bootstrap.js` in `config` folder (http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.bootstrap):

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  var fooer = require('./api/services/MyFoo.js');
  fooer.doFoo();  

  // It's very important to trigger this callback method when you are finished 
  // with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)
  cb();
};
```