# Bootstrap.js is not transpiled in time in sailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am writing my backend in sails js using es6/7 and I have defined a class that performs a background task.

Now from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608979/sails-js-background-processing-loop-not-related-to-connections) StackOverflow post I have learned that background tasks should be initiated at config/bootstrap.js. So I put the following inside that file:

```
import BackgroundService from '../api/services/backgroundService.js';

module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
  backgroundService= new BackgroundService();
  backgroundService.run();

  cb();
};
```

Now I'm getting typicall transpiler erros like:

```
  import BackgroundService from '../api/services/backgroundService.js';
  ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word[...]
```

or, when I replace the import with require:

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

(referring to the instantiation of the BackgroundService class)

This indicates that the files are either not transpiled in time or at all.
I couldn't find a solution to this yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your problem still exists, but it it does: nodejs currently doesn't support es6 `import`. You can either go the old way

```
const BackgroundService = require('../api/services/backgroundService.js');
```

or use babel. For sails I'd suggest [sails babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-babel)

Note: depending on your app's globals configuration you don't need to import `services` at all. If you have globals activated you can just directly call `backgroundService`